# What is the most popular cross-platform ink-capturing and displaying technology?

Tags: cross-platform, handwriting

I need to develop a simple application that allows the user to write some text and save it in the DB. It needs to be reasonably secure.

Unfortunately... it needs to work on both Windows and Mac, desktops, tablets, and all mobiles:(

Is there any such technology?:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to Qt - it's cross-platform, reliable and relatively easy to use.

Depending on what you want to do, an alternative would be to write a web application and let users access it with their web browser.

Comment: How is the status of Qt on "tablets and all mobiles"?

Comment: I doubt there is a framework that supports all existing mobiles on the planet, but Qt does support Symbian phones and some tablets. I'be updated my answer - creating a web app might be a better solution.